# Posting data from to api in angular/node

Tags: angular, api, post

i am sorry in advance if my question is redundant but i have been trying to solve this is for 2 days.

I have a form in angular at `localhost:4000`, i want to post its data to my api at `localhost:4000/api/scheduled` but each i get a 500 error.

Then this data might be sent from the api to mariadb.
I can realize get request from mariadb to angular but post don't work.

I precise it, but i think the error to post the form from angular to the api.

I tried many things like adapting the headers, the data sent by making it smaller...but nothing works.

```js
    onSubmitScheduled() {

        let OndemandScheduledRequest = this.formatRequestScheduled(this.selectedHotel, this.selectedCheckInDate, this.selectedCheckOutDate, this.selectedNumber, this.selectedCurrency, this.selectedReportName, this.selectedUser, this.selectedEmail, this.selectedFormat);
        console.log(OndemandScheduledRequest);
        this.saveScheduledRequest(OndemandScheduledRequest);
        this.openDialog();
      }

    saveScheduledRequest(onDemandScheduledRequest: OnDemandScheduledRequest) {
        console.log(onDemandScheduledRequest);

      /*  var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/form-data');
        */

       return this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/scheduled',onDemandScheduledRequest    )

    .subscribe(

           response => {
          debugger;
          console.log(response)
        },
      (err : HttpErrorResponse)=> console.log({
          err
        },))
      }
```

Here is the function to post the object which is defined in the interface (that i have imported):

```js
    export interface OnDemandScheduledRequest {
        id: string,
        user: string,
        email: string,


        reportName: string,
        format: string,
        submissionDate: string,


        Name: string,
        checkIn: string,
        checkOut: string,
        guests: string,
        currency: string,

      status: boolean,

    }
```

Here is the function which create an instance of this interface with the form fields:

```js
    formatRequestScheduled(selectedHotel, selectedCheckInDate, selectedCheckOutDate, selectedNumber, selectedCurrency, selectedReportName, selectedUser, selectedEmail, selectedFormat ) :
        //AS MANY RESULTS AS REQUESTED HORIZONS.
    any{

       let DemandScheduledRequest = {
         id: '1',

         user: selectedUser.toString(),
         email: selectedEmail.toString(),


         reportName: selectedReportName.toString(),
         format: selectedFormat.toString(),
         submissionDate: new Date(),


         Name: selectedHotel.toString(),
         checkIn: selectedCheckInDate,
         checkOut: selectedCheckOutDate,
         guests: selectedNumber.toString(),
         currency: selectedCurrency.toString(),


         status: false,
       }
        return DemandScheduledRequest;
      }
```

Thanks your for any help.

Comment: your node server running on localhost:4000 and your angular server running on Islocalhost:4000 too?

Comment: hey yes but i use /api and subroutes to separate the two sides

Get requests work with that

Comment: Have you tried changing the port numbers to see if that's where the problem is coming from?

Comment: yes but it stills doesn 't work..

Comment: Could you display the error message you're getting? Also it would be nice to confirm that the endpoint is reached

Comment: i get : POST http://localhost:4000/api/scheduled 500 (Internal Server Error)

How can i check if the endpoint is reached?

Comment: Can you try with convert your object to json string: let body = JSON.stringify(OndemandScheduledRequest); and then pass this body to post request this.http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/scheduled',body)

Comment: Also show your component code which handles /api in angular app

Comment: Usually there is some extra error message showing up, but ok. Do you get any errors displayed in your api's log?
To check if the endpoint is reached either put a breakpoint or a log statement as the first thing that happens when the code is reached.

Comment: so i tried to stringify but i still get the same error.

You mean the js file which handles the api routes?

Comment: Yes please your post request should handle there